# jquery ui layout height is too short

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, layout

I am trying to put a layout together with [jquery-ui-layout](http://layout.jquery-dev.net) and can't overcome the height problem.

Here's the HTML code:

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">
        <a class="logo" href="/">
            <img src="/media/bdo.png" width="154" height="38"/>
        </a>
        <ul class="top-menu">
            <li><a href="/">report fill out</a></li>
            <li><a href="/reports_browser/">browse reports</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="user">
            hi there
            </div>
    </div>
    <div id="content">

    <div class="ui-layout-west" id="consultants">west</div>
    <div class="ui-layout-center" id="contacts">center</div>
    <div class="ui-layout-east" id="details">east</div>

    </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
    <ul class="links">
        <li><a href="#">help</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">report an issue</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
```

There is [styles.css](http://pastebin.com/fHbtYDLb) I use for all the pages (it's rather large to past into here).

The javascript I use for this is rather simple, too:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    myLayout = $("#content").layout({
        applyDefaultStyles: true
    });
    myLayout.sizePane('west',500);
});
</script>
```

But the output is that all three panels are so short as per the screenshot below. How can I fix the height of the layout to fit the whole page and go all the way down to the footer?
[image]

Comment: the screenshot doesn't clearly display the height but it's shorter than a line's height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The layout manager will use the size of the container to determine it's layout logic. In this case you have not specified any height for the content div `<div id="content">...</div>`. Just as a quick example change your css like so:

```
#content {
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    padding: 10px 0 20px;
}
```

If you want to have the content `fill` the space between your header and footer you should use two layouts one for north (header), centre (content), south (footer) and again in your content you apply a second layout for your west, centre, east panels.